# Many threads with one operation for building time consuming objects in .net

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a GetProducts method that returns 20 products. Each product takes a considerable amount of time to create (many resources from many places).

Would you recommended spinning up 20 different threads (using the thread pool queue) to handle the creation of each product?

Will this cripple a server under a lot of load? My application has a risk of being under a high load.

The reason why I bring this up is because I have in-fact implemented something like this, and while doing load tests, my server gets brought to its knees and requires a full reboot to get back up and running normally.

Is there an approach I am missing? Am I doing it completely wrong? Should I stick to synchronous processing?

**NOTE**: When doing my load test, the servers memory was being used way to much, and sometimes and error was thrown (server out of memory). Is the garbage collector just not working fast enough?

Also, my products are being loaded from commerce server (which caches itself), but I have a lot of resources that need to be attached to the product(images, documents, reviews, etc).

Also, my architecture is a two tier setup with a web front end sitting entirely on wcf services (which does the threading). The wcf tier is what is getting crippled. The servers are virtual on an 8-core server with gb of ram allocated.

**PERSONAL NOTE** I have a feeling that I am abusing multi-theading. The call to "GetProducts" should be async, but "GetProducts" should NOT need be doing 20 async operations.

Comment: We need more info. Are products loaded from DB (if so, use proper indexes, views), web service, file,...?

Comment: Are you CPU bound? Or disk bound? Or network bound?

Comment: A few questions: 1) How many products are you dealing with in total?  2) If you were to create one product instead of 20, how long would it take?  3) How often do the products change?

Comment: Marc Gravell - I am CPU bound...

Comment: Hmm, that's very unlikely.  Easy to tell from taskmgr.exe, Perf tab, make sure they are all pegged at 100%, +0/-10.  And easy to solve, buy more silicon.  20+ cores to make 20 threads useful.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are CPU bound, spinning up 20 threads is probably overkill unless you have 20 cores **and** can dedicate them to this - I.e. not asp.net which will already be highly threaded.

Adding threading also makes synchronisation hard - I wonder indeed if your current implementation has deadlocked.

If te data is coming from different places, then async makes sense, but can be overdone.  In some ways, using pool threads might be tempting sice this won't totally steal processing one from the entire system (the pool has some inbuilt sanity, and will usually use < 20 threads to service 20 items).

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth thinking of a way to cache these products in memory.  If they take a long time to create, but don't change frequently you could create them when the server comes up, or as needed, or have another process create them and populate the cache that your webserver reads.

As mentioned by Marc, unless you have 20 cores to dedicate to this PER CONCURRENT CLIENT, you really aren't going to gain much by doing this.  I try to avoid multithreaded code in my web server if at all possible because it can lead to deadlocks if you are not careful.

Comment: Good point. Underload, GetProducts() could be called 20 times within a minute. Do they make 200 core servers? lol.